# Protobuf: Import known types (like timestamp) from google.golang.org/protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Until now, I was using `github.com/golang/protobuf`. Today I've received the warning `module github.com/golang/protobuf is deprecated: Use the "google.golang.org/protobuf" module instead.` So I did, and the transition went smoothly. But my project is still depending on `github.com/golang/protobuf`, the repo I want to get rid of. The reason is that I'm using known types in `.proto` files:

```protobuf
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
```

When I run `protoc` (`v3.12.4`) to generate the according Go files, this will be resolved to

```golang
import (
    timestamp "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"
    wrappers "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/wrappers"
)
```

, causing the deprecated dependency to be still in use.
Not sure whether it matters, but I'm relying on these `protoc` plugins:

```bash
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.30.0
$ go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.3.0
```

, which are the latest as far as I can tell.

Looking for the latest `timestamp` type, I stumbled upon https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb. The url suggests it might belong to the desired `google.golang.org/protobuf` package, but I don't know how to import it properly. The underlying github repo contains a readme that tells me:

```
types/known/timestamppb: Package timestamppb is the generated package for google/protobuf/timestamp.proto.
```

But `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto` is the import I'm currently using in my `.proto` file, and I'm still ending up with `import timestamp "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"`, which is the deprecated dependency.

I'm a bit lost on how all to figure out all this dependency resolving, and I don't know where to find the missing piece to get rid of `github.com/golang/protobuf` dependency. Is there any?

Comment: You're using a very old (July 2020) version (v3.12.4) of `protoc`. You should upgrade to a more recent version of `protoc` and of `protoc-gen-go` and `protoc-gen-go-grpc` in order to generate Go stubs that reference the new implementations of Google's Well-Known Types (WKT). The WKT references in your **protos** don't change (`google/protobuf/timestamp.proto`) but the generated stubs will be corrected.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for your response! Seems like `v3.12.4` is the latest version I can get with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade protobuf-compiler`, so I took it for the latest version. But I'll find a way! :)

Comment: @DazWilkin Way found. (I've installed the manually.) I wasn't expecting `protoc` to come with the logic for generated `go` files, but since the downloaded install files came with a `include` folder containing the types I was looking for, I can at least see where the solution is coming from. Feel free to create an answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: Glad it worked! You're correct, you shouldn't need to update `protoc` just the `protoc-gen-go*` plugins but, it's a good idea to maintain currency. I'll post as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's confusing because Google made a v1 (`github.com/golang/protobuf`) to v2 (`google.golang.org/protobuf`) change for Go.

The [README](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf#section-readme) for v2 provides a good synopsis and there was a blog post about this too (that I can no longer find) but see [A New Go API for Protocol Buffers](https://go.dev/blog/protobuf-apiv2).

This change (to v2) also included new (generated) Go (!) packages for Google's [Well-Known Types](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/) see [Package index](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf#readme-package-index).

A consequence of this changes is that you should update [`protoc-gen-go`](https://github.com/golang/protobuf)  and [`protoc-gen-go-grpc`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go) and, while you're at it, update `protoc` ([v3.12.4](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.12.4)) is old (July 2020). The new plugins will generate Go stubs that correctly reference the new GWT Go stubs provided by Google.

The `protoc-gen-go` release where the API switch occurred is [`1.4.0`](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/releases/tag/v1.4.0), see the "Overview".

The proto `import` references (e.g. `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto`) have **not** changed.

Comment: I might add: it's not updating `protoc` "while I'm at it" - it was the decisive thing to do to get rid of `github.com/golang/protobuf`.
And it might also be worth mentioning that the official installation [guide](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation) tells you first to use `apt`, but the `protoc` repo there is heavily outdated (and so is `snap`'s). Instead, you've gotta install it [manually](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/#install-pre-compiled-binaries-any-os). And don't forget to copy the `include/` folder, which is next to `bin/` but comes with the updated known types. ;)

Comment: Interesting. To your previous comment, given that Go code generation is done by the Go plugins, this should not have been necessary. Hmmm!? On Linux, if you add `protoc` to `PATH` then the `include` should be automatically included and not need extra work. Was that your experience?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was so surprised. And yes, the `bin/protoc` executable seems to look for a folder `../include/`, and this contained the (now updated) types.